# "GitHub Pages currently does not support IPv6" when using my domain registered at Google domains

Tags: github, google-domains

> Your site's DNS settings are using a custom subdomain, jacksonscott.net, 
>   that's set up with an AAAA record. GitHub Pages currently does not support 
>   IPv6. For more information, see https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-a-custom-domain-with-github-pages/.

This is my error when I try to apply my custom domain name jacksonscott.net, to my github pages repository.

Does anyone on here have experience with github pages and google domain, enough to the point where I could get some suggestions on what to do? I am new to web dev anything, however, I am a proficient computer science student in my senior year.

I have been to the github help page and I am still lost.

Comment: I think you should start with setting up the www subdomain to point to github, that looks like the easiest option for them: https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-a-www-subdomain/

Answer (score 5):

You've setup AAAA record(which is used for IPV6) instead of A records, that's why github display error that we don't have IPV6 address but still you're using AAAA record.

To setup A records simply use below example for Google domains.

[image]

The 151.101.1.195 was old IP for github pages(I am using that, but though I am not sure weather they have put any restiction to new user), but you can use their [new IP address.](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-an-apex-domain/#configuring-a-records-with-your-dns-provider)

> 185.199.108.153
>
> 185.199.109.153
>
> 185.199.110.153
>
> 185.199.111.153

If you simply put above 4 IP address as A records in Google Domain DNS setting then you can access your domain without any subdomain like example.com

If you want redirection from `www.example.com` to `example.com` then put `www` in NAME and `yourusername.github.io` in DATA field, and then use example.com in your Github CNAME file (not domain CNAME, it's github CNAME file). Here you can see [how github redirect automatically](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-an-apex-domain-and-www-subdomain/), when you specify domain name in github CNAME file.

Comment: Note: If you just let Google set up the forwarding, they do the AAAA record by default, and you need to do this instead (as of July 2019).

Answer (score 1):

You need to **set up an A record in the portal of your DNS provider**. Mapping one of these GitHub pages IPs

- `185.199.108.153`
- `185.199.109.153`
- `185.199.110.153`
- `185.199.111.153`

with an `A` record.

For instance: **A record (your-domain.example) =  185.199.108.153**

*Detailed instructions from GitHub Help are available here:
https://help.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/managing-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site#configuring-an-apex-domain*

Comment: That is only half the answer. If one wants absolutely IPv6 then the GitHub error forbids them.

Comment: Also, of course IP addresses can change at any time, so refer to the provider for the correct values to use at some point.